# Using C# Linq to test if string contains parts of a list of string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings called `TheListOfFruits "apple", "banana", "peach"`

I have a string called `TheFullString = "thebasketofapples"`

I want to know if TheFullString has **parts of it** contained in TheListOfFruits

For now, this is what I do:

```
foreach(string s in TheListOfFruits)
{
    if (TheFullString.Contains(s) == true)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

So in this case, `"thebasketofapples"` contains `"apple"`

Is there a nice Linq-way to write this?

Comment: Regex might be a better tool here depending on the various strings involved. What if you needed to tell the difference between "apple" and "apples"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1) returns true if an element satisfies a condition. This code is equivalent to yours:

```
if(TheListOfFruits.Any(s => TheFullString.Contains(s))
{
   return;
}
```

Comment: Which can be shortened to: `if (TheListOfFruits.Any(TheFullString.Contains)) return;`

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this using linq using Any function

```
if (TheListOfFruits.Any(t => TheFullString.Contains(t))) 
{
   return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
var theListOfFruits = new List<string>() { "apple", "banana", "peach" };
        var theFullString = "thebasketofapples";

        bool result = theListOfFruits.Any(a => theFullString.Contains(a));
```